# Background images on options

Tags: html, css

I'd like to get a `<select>` element where each `<option>` is labelled with an icon.

I can achieve this using `<select size="5">`, by applying a background image to the `<select>` that has each icon coincide with an option, but that relies strongly on the height of the `<option>` being predictable (which is isn't).

I can apply individual background colours to different options, so why not a background image?

Actually, this question can be extended to cover "What style properties can and can't be used on `<option>` tags?"

Comment: Argh. I hate styling `<select>`s. Consider using a custom one (à la [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)) and be free to style everything to your liking :)

Comment: I think `<option>` ignores all rules except for `color` and `background-color`.

Comment: [Ugly hack](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tZUbE/)? Meh heheheheh. ([Regular sized](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tZUbE/1/), too, but note that when you select an option with without more than one size, you can't see the `option`. And, no doubt, it only works in Firefox.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reliably style elements like that across browsers; some of them will allow you to insert backgrounds and such, some will not.

If you want guaranteed cross-browser compatibility the only way is to use custom widgets instead of `<select>` elements.

If you are OK with limited compatibility, state your target browsers.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you cannot add images to option tags since they only support text. The only way to achieve your desired effect is to make your own "select" using javascript/jquery